# Java - signIn not working as expected

Tags: java, android

So I have been working on a little project of my own, The problem I am facing is It is working but the startActivity is executing before the signIn() method is done executing, i.e, after completing the activity I am getting a popup for selection of the Email account.

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
        signIn();
    }
    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    finish();
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

And, the app is not working when the internet is not available, how do I make it to work? It crashes with the message "Unfortunately App has stopped."

Comment: If signIn is running asynchronously (which it must be if networking is involved) you will need to implement a callback interface that waits for a response and then starts the activity.

Comment: I din't thought of threading or Asynctask as I don't have any experience with it but thanks anyway I will try to implement it in AsyncTask as provided in the answer below

Comment: Mind posting your code for signIn()? I might be able to help a bit more if you are still having trouble

Comment: <!--language: java-->private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

Comment: It isn't a race case, it is an if/else thing. Your logic is off.

Comment: @zgc7009 My logic is off, Can you explain it a further more?

Comment: This could be solved by doing this `if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) signIn(); else startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));` then finish it off with your overridePendingTransition call and your finish call. The way you have it now stacks activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to catch exception ( which exception you get )

```
private void signIn() {
    try{
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        //write to us your ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [Check network connectivity for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android)  , do this before doing any network operations and notify user with the dialogbox if not connected to internet .

Regarding the activity starts before signIn() function is complete , i would recommend to use AsyncTask() for this ,

- in onpreexceute() you can show the the progress dialog .
- in doinBackground() put signIn() function
- in onpostexeceute() start the activity

for AsyncTask Referece Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) .

Good Luck .

Comment: Choose this answer as correct if you find this helpful and has resolved your issue :) .

Comment: I did that for the net connection the problem is the app crashes when trying to open the app without the internet connection.

Comment: can u post the error log image of android studio or some info on error  that causing the app to crash......

Comment: I was able to implement AsyncTask now it works only problem is the app crashes when internet is not available.

Comment: can u post the error log image of android studio or some info on error that causing the app to crash...... u can find the details of the error in android monitor in android studio .